# Регулярные выражение для параметров шин и дисков

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста составить регулярные выражение для получения параметров шин/дисков.

Для шин необходимо из строки **245/45 R18** , получить 245 , 45 , 18.

Для дисков из строки **8 x 18 ET49** , получить 8, 18, 49

Comment: По сути - удалить всё нецифровое и сделать строго по одному пробелу между числами, что ли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно удобнее будет матчить в ассоциативный массив

```
$s = '245/45 R18';

preg_match('/^(?<width>\d+)\/(?<height>\d+)\sR(?<size>\d+)$/u', $s, $m);
var_dump($m);
```

на выходе получаем массив с именованными полями

```
array(7) { 
    [0]=> string(10) "245/45 R18" 
    ["width"]=> string(3) "245" 
    [1]=> string(3) "245" 
    ["height"]=> string(2) "45" 
    [2]=> string(2) "45" 
    ["size"]=> string(2) "18" 
    [3]=> string(2) "18" 
}
```

аналогично можно именовать для дисков

```
^(?<count>\d+)\sx\s(?<dia>\d+)\sET(?<ET>\d+)$
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, должно получиться так:

```
preg_match('/(\d+)/(\d+) R(\d+)/', '245/45 R18', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

и так:

```
preg_match('/(\d+) x (\d+) ET(\d+)/', '8 x 18 ET49', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Кто-то решил подпортить вам репутацию :-D

Comment: @Эдуард, ага, бывает )

Answer (score 1):

`/^(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)$/\1 \2 \3/gm`

[fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/y7dO6f/1)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а как работать не только с целыми числами, но и дробными, отрицательными Например 8.5 x 18.5 ET-49.5 https://regex101.com/r/y7dO6f/2

Comment: Если идти по пути дополнения моей регулярки, то см. https://regex101.com/r/y7dO6f/3

Answer (score 1):

**UPD**: прочитал комментарий к вопросу, решение уже было предложено @Akina

```php
$str = '245/45 R18
8 x 18 ET49';
$result = preg_replace('/[^\d\n\r]+/', ',', $str);
```

Как вариант можно заменить все символы отличные от цифры или знака перевода строки на запятую, или пробел, вообщем разделитель можно указать любой

Результат:

```txt
245,45,18
8,18,49
```